# Notion of Breaking Symmetry in Fourier Analysis by E. Stein

Tags: analysis, fourier-analysis

On page 86 of Fourier Analysis by E. Stein.

$f_N:=\sum_{1\le |n|\le N}\frac{e^{in\theta}}{n}, \bar f_N:=\sum_{-N \le n \le -1}\frac{e^{in\theta}}{n}$. And $P_N=e^{i(2N)\theta}f_N, \bar P_N=e^{i(2N)\theta}\bar f_N$. So far, I understand what he is doing.

But then he says $S_M$ is the partial sum and gave a lemma：
$S_M(P_N)=
\begin{cases}
P_N  & \text{if }M\ge 3N \\
\bar P_N & \text{if }M=2N  \\
0 &  \text{if }M\lt N
\end{cases}$.

I am confused with the notation $S_M(P_N)$, I do not know what it stands for. Any clarification is greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: I believe $S_M(f)$ is the $M$th partial sum of the Fourier series of $f$